# Visual Studio 2019, Android and CMake

Tags: android, cmake, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to create a Visual Studio 2019 solution of my existing C++ project (.so) so I can have access to native debugging on Android.

I already installed the [Cross-platform mobile development tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/cross-platform-mobile-development-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019#build-an-app-for-android-ios-and-windows-c) and the sample projects seem to work fine.
So my conclusion is that Visual Studio 2019 indeed supports what I'm trying to achieve.

However, the problem happens when I try to use CMake to create a Visual Studio solution for Android. I get this error:

```
CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME is 'Android' but 'NVIDIA Nsight Tegra Visual Edition' is not installed.
```

And it's true, I don't have "NVIDIA Nsight Tegra" installed, but the sample projects from VS worked without it so I'm assuming that the NVIDIA tool is not really needed.

Searching the web I came across this [old post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/support-for-android-cmake-projects-in-visual-studio/) which said we have to use a custom CMake version, but again, the sample projects are not using any custom CMake (i think).

Any tips on how I should move from here?